# I need to delete the object list by using matched key. (example the key have 1 and 2 , the result will only show 3)

Tags: javascript

```
let selectedRow = ["1","2","3"]; 

let arr = [ 
   { id:1, name:"eddie" }, 
   { id:2, name:"jake" }, 
   { id:3, name:"susan" }, 
];
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome from the example data you provided? I really can't understand the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+filter+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: inside the state of arr will be left [ { id:3, name:"susan" } ]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please write a *summarized* title and put the rest of the explanations in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Updation on the answer provided by Andy, If you don't want to update the exiting array and want to result in a new array

```js
let selectedRow = ["1", "2"];

let arr = [
    { id: 1, name: "eddie" },
    { id: 2, name: "jake" },
    { id: 3, name: "susan" },
];

const result = arr.filter(item => !selectedRow.includes(item.id.toString()))
console.log(result)
```

2. If you want changes in a current array and don't want to store results in a new array (Not the most efficient solution though)

```js
let selectedRow = ["1", "2"];

let arr = [
    { id: 1, name: "eddie" },
    { id: 2, name: "jake" },
    { id: 3, name: "susan" },
];

for (const row of selectedRow) {
    const index = arr.findIndex(item => item.id.toString() === row)
    if (index !== -1)
        arr.splice(index, 1)
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: You can also create a new array of numbers with `['1', '2'].map(Number)` :)

Comment: I thought it would be better to avoid one more loop for map() and rather go with converting id to string for comparison.

Your thoughts?

Comment: At this point it's just a matter of opinion. Developers have their own style. Neither solution is wrong at this point.

Comment: Agreed with you

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your `selectedRow` array is an array of numbers (because your object ids are numbers).
2. [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) over the array of objects and only keep the ones that `selectedRow` doesn't [`include`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'eddie' }, { id: 2, name: 'jake' }, { id: 3, name: 'susan' }];

const selectedRow = ['1', '2'].map(Number); 

const result = arr.filter(obj => {
  return !selectedRow.includes(obj.id);
});

console.log(result);
```